# Ant Deploy Windows Desktop User Current Directory Zip File

Tags: windows, deployment, ant, build, desktop

Hi I am trying to set up Ant in Eclipse to deploy in two places one is with in the project (works fine)...

Now I want to drops my zipped code onto my desktop which would be C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop

Ok But if I wanted to distribute this to other developers the C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop would be C:\Users\TheirAccount\Desktop

There must be a way to wild card or get the current users MyAccount\ThierAccount (so this would be have the same everywhere).

Anyone ever encounter something like this?

So here is my malfunction:

```
<target name="zipme2">
    <zip destfile="C:\Users\%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\${projectDescription.name}.${touch.time}.zip" basedir="../" excludes="**/*.zip"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ${user.home} property to represent home folder.
So the complete location would look like this:

```
${user.home}/Desktop/${projectDescription.name}.${touch.time}.zip
```

And use only forward slashes. Ant will convert them to system-specific.